# AllCharge payment website integration-- PHP

Tags: php

we use the following form to integrate with allcharge system. we use 'noview' for not showing your interface to the users but it not works and take the user to your interface. need help?

http://gsimarkets.com/wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/bank_tranfer.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide all from from the page you can use css style:

```
<from style="display:none">
```

If you want to hide input elements you can use type="hidden":

```
<input type="hidden" />
```